# In Windows Installer, when should one schedule a custom action to generate a value for a property?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3

The problem I'm trying to solve is that the installer needs to create a user that will, in turn, be used as the identity under which a Windows Service runs.  It works fine with hardcoded values.

What I'd like to do next is to provide sensible defaults when doing a typical installation, by generating a cryptographically strong password. There is no use case where someone will need to sign using this credential via RDP or as a user.

I wrote a custom action to generate the password:

```
public class CustomActions
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult GeneratePassword(Session session)
    {
        session.Log("Begin " + nameof(GeneratePassword));
        session["MY_PASSWORD"] = GenerateComplexPassword(24);
        session.Log("Completed " + nameof(GeneratePassword));
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }

    public static string GenerateComplexPassword(int length = 25)
    {
        // 
    }
}
```

In `Product.wxs`, the binary is registered and referenced. For now, I'd like to view the password generated, so it is not marked as being hidden or secure. That will come once I have it working.

```
<Wix>
    <Product>

        <Property Id="MY_USERNAME" Value="my-username" />
        <Property Id="MY_PASSWORD" Value=" " />  

        <Binary Id="MyCustomActions.CA.dll" src="$(var.CustomActions.TargetDir)\MyCustomActions.CA.dll" />

        <CustomAction Id="ValidateUsername"
                    Return="check"
                    Execute="immediate"
                    BinaryKey="MyCustomActions.CA.dll"
                    DllEntry="ValidateUsername" />

        <CustomAction Id="ValidatePassword"
                    Return="check"
                    Execute="immediate"
                    BinaryKey="MyCustomActions.CA.dll"
                    DllEntry="ValidatePassword" />

        <CustomAction Id="GeneratePassword"
                    Return="check"
                    Execute="immediate"
                    BinaryKey="MyCustomActions.CA.dll"
                    DllEntry="GeneratePassword" />

        <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="GeneratePassword" After="CostFinalize"></Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>

    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <!-- omitted -->
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <!-- omitted -->
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

When I run the installer, there is no sign in the logs that the property `MY_PASSWORD` was updated by a custom action, or that the custom action was ever called.

However, my UI does show that the `ValidateUsername` and `ValidatePassword` actions are called.

How would one schedule the custom action so that when the dialog is displayed, the property is already set?

Comment: Your `Product.wxs` is incomplete if you state that both `ValidateUsername` and `ValidatePassword` run, you did not schedule them in the sample we see. Look in the log for the condition on the `GeneratePassword` action and how it evaluates. You are using an end-tag versus an empty-element tag which may behave differently as inner text describes a condition. You might set the inner text to "1" to always evaluate as true.

Comment: You can also look in the InstallExecute table of the built MSI using something like Orca to make sure that custom action is scheduled and has the proper condition.

If I were doing something similar I would schedule it before InstallInitialize so after CostFinalize is a good place.

Comment: The code is located at https://github.com/Phaka/phaka-selenium-installer. It was a bit too much to add to the question.

Comment: Post those verbose logs somewhere.

Comment: @Ritmo2k The condition was the real reason it didn't get executed. I added it to `InstallUISequence` and `InstallExecuteSequence` and to run after `AppSearch`. But it was the missing condition that caused it not to run.  Please create an answer and so I can give you the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable a log and see how the [Custom](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/custom.html) element's condition is evaluated. In your case, the inner text being empty evaluates to false and therefor the action wont execute. Set the inner text to `1` to always evaluate to true, or use a [condition](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/expression-syntax/) that suits your need.